# How to add x-xsrf-token using HttpClientXsrfModule angular 6

Tags: angular, authentication, csrf, csrf-protection, csrf-token

I am using the `JWT` token for the authentication and storing that in local storage and now wanted to add `CSRF` token with that, is it possible to activate `CSRF` just in angular?

As JWT token generate is it possible to generate `CSRF` randomly with that and store it?

I am trying to something like below

authentication.service.ts

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
    import { map } from 'rxjs/operators/map';
    import { Router } from '@angular/router';

    export interface UserDetails {
    _id: string;
    email: string;
    name: string;
    exp: number;
    iat: number;
    }

    interface TokenResponse {
  token: string;
   }

   export interface TokenPayload {
  email: string;
  password: string;
  name?: string;
}

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {
  private token: string;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) {}

  private saveToken(token: string): void {
    localStorage.setItem('mean-token', token);
    this.token = token;
  }

  private getToken(): string {
    if (!this.token) {
      this.token = localStorage.getItem('mean-token');
    }
    return this.token;
  }

  public getUserDetails(): UserDetails {
    const token = this.getToken();
    let payload;
    if (token) {
      payload = token.split('.')[1];
      payload = window.atob(payload);
      return JSON.parse(payload);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  public isLoggedIn(): boolean {
    const user = this.getUserDetails();
    if (user) {
      return user.exp > Date.now() / 1000;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  private request(method: 'post'|'get', type: 'login'|'register'|'profile', user?: TokenPayload): Observable<any> {
    let base;

    if (method === 'post') {
      base = this.http.post(`/api/${type}`, user);
    } else {
      base = this.http.get(`/api/${type}`, { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${this.getToken()}` }});
    }

    const request = base.pipe(
      map((data: TokenResponse) => {
        if (data.token) {
          this.saveToken(data.token);
        }
        return data;
      })
    );

    return request;
  }

  public register(user: TokenPayload): Observable<any> {
    return this.request('post', 'register', user);
  }

  public login(user: TokenPayload): Observable<any> {
    return this.request('post', 'login', user);
  }

  public profile(): Observable<any> {
    return this.request('get', 'profile');
  }

  public logout(): void {
    this.token = '';
    window.localStorage.removeItem('mean-token');
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
  }
}
```

auth.interceptor.ts

```
import { Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpEvent, HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpXsrfTokenExtractor } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class HttpXsrfInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private tokenExtractor: HttpXsrfTokenExtractor) {
  }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const headerName = 'X-XSRF-TOKEN';
    let token = this.tokenExtractor.getToken() as string;
    if (token !== null && !req.headers.has(headerName)) {
      req = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set(headerName, token) });
    }
    return next.handle(req);
  }

}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClientXsrfModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ProfileComponent } from './profile/profile.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './register/register.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { AuthenticationService } from './authentication.service';
import { AuthGuardService } from './auth-guard.service';
import { HttpXsrfInterceptor } from './auth.interceptor';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
  { path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuardService] }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ProfileComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
    HomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    HttpClientXsrfModule.withOptions({
      cookieName: 'My-Xsrf-Cookie', 
      headerName: 'My-Xsrf-Header' 
    }),
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
  ],
  providers: [
   { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: HttpXsrfInterceptor, multi: true },
    AuthenticationService, 
    AuthGuardService

  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```